# QSqlDatabase open always returns true after update

Tags: mysql, qt, qt5.5, qt5.6

After updating Qt from 5.5 to 5.6 QSqlDatabase:open always returns true - even if the host is not reachable and/or username/password/database settings are set to nonsense.

Test code:

```
QSqlDatabase* db = new QSqlDatabase(QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL", "TESTCONNECTION"));
db->setHostName(ip);
db->setPort(port);
db->setUserName(user);
db->setPassword(pwd);
db->setDatabaseName(dbName);
db->setConnectOptions("MYSQL_OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT=4");
bool ok = db->open();
```

I compiled the Qt sql libs against the latest mysql version (5.6.x).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was actually a reported bug: [QSqlDatabase::open always returns true with QMYSQL](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-47784). The page shows that it was solved at 15/Sep/15 7:03 AM and implemented in version [5.5.1](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG/fixforversion/15105/?selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.jira-projects-plugin:version-summary-panel), but this however is before the [5.6 alpha release](https://wiki.qt.io/Qt-5.6-release), which was on 8/Sep/15, so that explains why it is not yet fixed in your version.

Comment: Thank you very much. This was/is annoying as ****. Tried it on 5.5.0 and 5.6 with three different versions of mysql (5.1, 5.5, 5.6) and still got the same behaviour. I really don't know why i did not find the bug report. Cheers.

Comment: onwhenready - Can you please add details as how did applying patch solve the problem and steps for applying patch? Having exact same problem in my application. TIA